# How to upload file to AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, server, scp

Hey I am trying to upload a folder of file from my local ubuntu os to aws ubuntu server for that I have tried filezilla and it work perfect but when I am trying to use this command :

```
 sudo scp -i ~/Desktop/jumpbook.pem ~/Desktop/ommlogo.png  ubuntu@ec2-52-24-103-139.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~/var/
```

I am getting this error :

-bash: /home/nilay/Desktop/jumpbook.pem: Permission denied

How can I upload files to aws cloud server .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ls -l /home/nilay/Desktop/jumpbook.pem` to check pem file permissions.

It should be *-r--------*. Otherwise, execute `chmod 400 /home/nilay/Desktop/jumpbook.pem` and try scp again.